# How to make PPSX presentation to loop in PowerPoint Viewer 2010

Tags: presentations, viewer, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I want to use a standalone PC to run some PowerPoint presentation countinously. I have installed PowerPoint Viewer 2010 on it as well as the ppsx presentation file.

But the viewer plays the file once and finishes with the message like "End of slideshow, press a key to end".

Any ideas how to make PPSX presentation to loop in PowerPoint Viewer 2010?

PS.When using the /F switch it opens in fullscreen mode, but still not repeating.

Comment: There is a bugfix in PowerPoint Viewer 2010 Service Pack 1 to solve this. SP1 can be downloaded from http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=26620

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, converted to WMV and plays with Windows Media Player

Answer (score 1):

Go to set up slide show

office 2007- You shall find the option under the Slide Show tab.

in the `set up` box, there is a button titled `Set Up Slide Show`

then click the Loop continuously till esc

then save it as whatever file. It should loop continuously.

I believe that in older versions, its under Slide Show, next to File Edit etc. I forgot what you call that part.

Comment: The presentation is looped already and it works as desired in PowerPoint. Unfortunately, in the PPT Viewer doesn't :/

Answer (score 0):

If using PowerPoint Viewer 2010, check that you have SP1 installed.  There is a known bug that does not acknowledge kiosk mode.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=26620